# How can I convert multiple numbers in a textbox to int, in C#?

Tags: c#

For a programming assignment, I have to make a simple dice game in Visual C#. A part of this game is displaying a list of the values, and seeing whether the total of the values is over a certain number.
I currently have a textbox that displays the individual values separated by a newline, and am currently using `iPlayer1Total += int.Parse(player1TxtBox.Text);`, but this only seems to do the first line of the textbox.

Comment: first off never use int.parse in a textbox, god knows what the user could have put in that textbox, could be a string! use int.tryparse(); that way if it fails you can make it output an error message, instead of crashing the program

Comment: Are the values entered by user or are they results of dice rolls your app performs? If you generate the values you should already have them stored and could reuse them instead of parsing them from a GUI element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using multiline textbox. First split your string on "\n\r" and then:

```
string[] strArray =player1TxtBox.Text.Split("\n\r".ToCharArray());
```

then

```
        int iPlayer1Total = 0;
        foreach (string str in strArray)
        {
            int temp =0;
            int.TryParse(str, out temp);
            iPlayer1Total  += temp;
         }
```

Edit: a better option to split would be:

```
var strArray  = player1TxtBox.Text.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: the start of this answer "It seems that" reminded me horribly of that annoying paper clip from microsoft products *shivers*

Comment: You might want to do int.TryParse since a textbox could have non ints entered into it.  throw out or handle (error) if you can't parse

Comment: @Habib.OSU thats the one, extremely similar though, which is why it reminded me of it i guess xD

Answer (score 3):

Split the string into an array along the newline.

String.split should get you there.

Then parse each value and voila

Answer (score 1):

You should split your text into string array. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
string[] list = player1TxtBox.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and then use

```
foreach(string num in list)
   iPlayer1Total += int.Parse(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN library is your friend. Check out the entry on the TextBox and you will find what you're looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx

Hint: Note the `Lines` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
string[] str = textbox.Text.Split(@"\n\r");

int a=0;

for(int i=0; i< str.Length; i++)
   a += int.TryParse(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to assume, since it is dice, that each value will only be a single character.

```
string t = "125 yhsd 7,8+2";
List<int> diceValues=new List<int>();
foreach (char c in t)
{
    int o=0;
    int.TryParse(c.ToString(),out o);
    if (o > 0 && o < 7)
    diceValues.Add(o);
}
```

output should be

diceValues
1
2
5
2

I didn't test this or compile it so there might be errors